# Problem with component update when using Context

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

**Technologies** - ReactJS + TailwindCSS

I'm trying to create a section in my app where users are presented a cloud of tags and, when users click on them, an array of the selected tags is passed to a new view. Tags are styled when they have been selected by the user.

To implement this I created a parent component that renders a list of a component I called Badge. The Badge component uses a state variable called isSelected to handle the styling, and also use the Context to insert the value in the array of selected tags.

Individually, each part of the code seems to work fine (Badges are correctly styled when selected, and values are inserted into the context array and can be accessed to from other components) but when I update the state of the component and modify the Context at the same time, while the values are added to the array, the Badge component won't reflect the styles changes when clicked.

**CODE**

```
import PropTypes, { bool } from 'prop-types'
import { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import { SkillsContext } from "../context"

function Badge({ className, text, selected = false }) {
  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(selected)
  const { skills, setSkills } = useContext(SkillsContext)

  if (isSelected) {
    className += ' bg-primary text-black'
  } else {
    className += ' text-white ring-1 ring-inset ring-white'
  }

  const handleSelection = () => {
    setSkills((prev) => [...prev, text])
    setIsSelected((prev) => !prev)
  }

  return (
    <span id="badge" className={`inline-flex items-center rounded-full px-2 md:px-4 py-1 text-sm md:text-base ml-0 font-thin cursor-pointer ${className}`} onClick={handleSelection}>
      {text}
    </span>
  )
}

Badge.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
  text: PropTypes.string,
  selected: bool
}

export default Badge
```

To be honest, I'm not sure how to proceed. I'm pretty sure this has something to do with React's component lifecycle, but the code seems OK to me.

I tried wrapping the styling condition into useEffect and run it whenever isSelected changes, but that wouldn't load the styles at all.

```
useEffect(() => {
 if (isSelected) {
    className += ' bg-primary text-black'
  } else {
    className += ' text-white ring-1 ring-inset ring-white'
  }

}, [isSelected])
```

As per request I'm adding the parent components code:

```
import Button from "../components/Button"
import Badge from "../components/Badge"
import { SkillsContext } from "../context"

import { I18N } from "../i18n"
import { useState } from "react"

function HomeSkills() {
  const { title, skillList, button } = I18N.skills
  const [ skills, setSkills ] = useState([])

  return (
    <SkillsContext.Provider value={{ skills, setSkills }}>
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="py-24 px-5 md:px-12 flex flex-col items-center">
            <h2 className="text-white mb-12">{ title }</h2>
            <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center gap-4 mb-12">
              { skillList.map((skill) => <Badge key={crypto.randomUUID()} text={skill} /> ) }
            </div>
            <Button text={button} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </SkillsContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default HomeSkills
```

**Context.js**

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const SkillsContext = createContext()
```

Comment: Do the class names change on the `<Badge>` components? Consider providing code for the parent component.

Comment: Yes... className contains the expected string. It is the component that is not being updated when setSkills is used

Comment: Consider checking the `content` file globs in the Tailwind configuration sufficiently cover the file that contains the `Badge` component code.

Answer (score -1):

Don't modify the props you pass to your component.

Here is an possible solution:

```js
const classNameInner = isSelected ? ' bg-primary text-black' : ' text-white ring-1 ring-inset ring-white'

//...
<span id="badge" className={`inline-flex items-center rounded-full px-2 md:px-4 py-1 text-sm md:text-base ml-0 font-thin cursor-pointer ${className} ${classNameInner}`} onClick={handleSelection}>
```

You can use`no-param-reassign` eslint rule to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that is not the issue. If I don't modify the context the modified prop works fine. I tried your solution anyway and it makes no difference. Thank you though.